# Android studio New update XML preview are not in Electric Eel Patch 2

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio New update XML preview is not loading properly kindly let us know your comments, please it works as expected in ***Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2*** and below

[image]

Need a solution why the XML preview is not loading properly

Comment: I am using latest version of Android studio electric eil. But I am not facing this problem. My android studio is working well.

Answer (score 0):

You can preview the XML in the Layout Validation tab.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

The Layout Inspector in Android Studio allows you to debug the layout of your app by showing a view hierarchy and allowing you to inspect the properties of each view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).